# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class ClassDefinition could not be converted to string Concrete.php

Tags: php, pimcore

On pimcore Version: 3.1.1 (Build: 3543) I get the following error in php.log but no errors in pimcore debug.log.

```
[29-Jan-2016 16:28:13 Europe/Berlin] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Pimcore\Model\Object\ClassDefinition could not be converted to string in /opt/bitnami/apps/pimcore/htdocs/pimcore/models/Webservice/Data/Object/Concrete.php on line 104
```

I get HTTP 500 Internal server error response from a custom WebService.

How can I investigate it ?Is there already a resolution for this error?

The pimcore source code line that generates error (Concrete.php) is the following:

```
throw new \Exception("No element [ " . $element->name . " ] of type [ " . $element->type . " ] found in class definition " . $class);
```

So it seems due to a wrong error-handling.

Comment: We need some code to help...

Comment: You get an error trying what? Need some code please

Comment: The solution to this issue is to not try to use an object as a string.

Comment: my question is not only related on how to solve the error (it seems a Pimcore product issue in handling some bad data/configuration) but on how to investigate it.

Comment: The error is about converting an object to string (probably an object without method `__toString()`), so, i.e., in your error-handling, the `$class` what is? you use `$class` as string, but maybe it's an object. In this case, you can try with `get_class($class)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug (https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/422) is now solved and planned to be released in Pimcore 4.0.0

To investigate I used `error_log`, `get_class`, `gettype` PHP functions:

```
error_log(" found in class definition [ " . get_class($class));
error_log("variable 'class' type = " . gettype($class));
error_log("'class->name' = " . $class->name);
```

Thanks to @fusion3k for the help in identifying the correct part of the code-line that was giving the error and the syntax `get_class($class)`.